# How to add a where clause on a linq join (lambda)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I have two database tables Contact (Id, Name, ...) and ContactOperationalPlaces (ContactId, MunicipalityId), where a contact can be connected to several ContactOperationalPlaces.

What I'm trying to do is to build a query (ASP .NET, C#) with IQueryable, that only selects all the contacts that exists in the ContactOperationalPlaces table, with a given MunicipalityId.

The sql query looks like this:

```
select * from Contacts c 
right join ContactOperationPlaces cop on c.Id = cop.ContactId 
where cop.MunicipalityId = 301;
```

With linq it would look something like this:

```
//_ctx is the context
var tmp = (from c in _ctx.Contacts
             join cop in _ctx.ContactOperationPlaces on c.Id equals cop.ContactId
             where cop.MunicipalityId == 301
             select c);
```

So, I know how to do this if the point was to select all of this at once, unfortunately it's not. I'm building a query based on user input, so I don't know all of the selection at once.

So this is what my code looks like:

```
IQueryable<Contacts> query = (from c in _ctx.Contacts select c);
//Some other logic....
/*Gets a partial name (string nameStr), and filters the contacts 
 so that only those with a match on names are selected*/
query = query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(nameStr);
//Some more logic
//Gets the municipalityId and wants to filter on it! :( how to?
query = query.where(c => c.ContactOperationalPlaces ...........?);
```

The difference with the two where statements is that with the first one, each contact has only one name, but with the latter a contact can contain several operational places...

I have managed to find one solution, but this solution gives me an unidentyfied object, that contains both of the tables. And I don't know how to proceed with it.

```
query.Join(_ctx.ContactOperationPlaces, c => c.Id, cop => cop.ContactId,
      (c, cop) => new {c, cop}).Where(o => o.cop.municipalityId == 301);
```

The object returned from this expression is System.Linq.Iqueryable<{c:Contact, cop:ContactOperationalPlace}>, and it can't be cast to Contacts...

So, that's the issue. The answer is probably pretty simple, but I just can't find it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You create an anonymous type with both objects before your where clause and filter it on ContactOperationPlaces value. You just have to select the Contact after that.

```
query.Join(_ctx.ContactOperationPlaces, c => c.Id, cop => cop.ContactId,
           (c, cop) => new {c, cop}).Where(o => o.cop.municipalityId == 301)
                                    .Select(o => o.c)
                                    .Distinct();
```

Comment: and probably add Distinct() for contact

Comment: Thank u so much! I knew that the solution would be pretty simple once I found it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return new objects in the result selector function. The delegate provides both variables so you can choose one or the other, or some other variation (which would require a new object). Try this:

```
query.Join(_ctx.ContactOperationPlaces, c => c.Id, cop => cop.ContactId,
  (c, cop) => c).Where(o => o.cop.municipalityId == 301);
```

Comment: I've tried this before, and since i don't do like this: (c, cop) => new {c, cop}, I won't get the opportunity to select cop in the where clause...

Answer (score 0):

can you just cast it to var and try to use intellisense on it?

```
 var myCast = query.Join(_ctx.ContactOperationPlaces, c => c.Id, cop => cop.ContactId,
  (c, cop) => new {c, cop}).Where(o => o.cop.municipalityId == 301);
```

Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much easier if you start this as 2 different queries, then combine them. I'm assuming  the relation is Contact (1 <-> many) Contactoperationplaces ? And in the end, you will be showing 1 item per Contactoperationplaces, not 1 item per Contact?

Do it like this:

```
IQueryable<Contacts> query = (from c in _ctx.Contacts select c);

...

query = query.Where(x=> x.Name.ToLower().Contains(nameStr.ToLower());

...

IQueryable<ContactOperationPlaces> query_2 =
     (from c in _ctx.ContactOperationPlaces
       where query.Where(x=> x.Name == c.Contact.Name).Count() > 0
       select c);

 //Now query_2 contains all contactoperationsplaces which have a contact that was found in var query
```

Conversely, there is a much easier way to do this, and that's by skipping the first part entirely.

```
IQueryable<ContactOperationPlaces> query_2 =
     (from c in _ctx.ContactOperationPlaces
       where c.Contact.Name.ToLower().Contains(strName.ToLower())
       select c);
```

If you're using Entity Framework, you don't have to do any joins as long as you defined associations between the tables.

Now that I look at it, my second solution is far more efficient and easier. But if you need to do some other processing inbetween these commands, solution one works too :)

If you need more explanation, feel free to ask :)

Comment: I want to keep the contact that has a connection to a specific municipationId in contactoperationalplaces, so i want one item per contact. I know the latter solution is the best, but as I explained in my question, I can't select all at once.

Comment: are these different tables connected throug a one-to-many association? If so, this is your best solution. If you have other joins on which contact relies, you should replaces those by doing something similar like the above.
As EF does all the joining for you and you have to only say what you want, I think manually joining tables against EF is inefficient by default (except for some very, very unusual situations perhaps). Not blaming you, but I'd suggest steering clear from doing manual joins as you will have to do more work, with less feedback/debugging...